# Why is this algorithm slow in Python compared to its VB.net implementation?

Tags: python

The following code takes around two minutes to run on Python 3.3, but an equivalent VB.net version runs in less than one second. Is there a particular inefficiency I've done here that makes it slow on Python? Or is it just a slower interpreter? Could Python's math library be that much slower? (Initializing x, x1, and x3 to float doesn't make much difference).

##### Python:

```
inc = 2*3*5*7
for x in range(inc,200000,inc):
    n = 0
    y = x * x + x

    for x1 in range(x+1, y):
        x2 = x1 / (x1 - x) * x
        x3 = round(x2)
        if abs(x2 - x3) < 0.0000001:
            if x3 < x1: break
            n += 1
    if n > 500: print(x, n)
```

(I realize there are better algorithms to accomplish the same thing. I'm interested in improving the Python implementation of this, in order to learn more Python.)

##### VB Code:

```
Dim x, x1, x2, x3, y As Double
Dim n As Integer

For x = 0 To 200000 Step 2 * 3 * 5 * 7
  n = 0
  y = x * x + x
  For x1 = x + 1 To y
    x2 = x1 / (x1 - x) * x
    x3 = Round(x2)
    If Math.Abs(x2 - x3) < 0.0000001 Then
      If x3 < x1 Then Exit For
      n += 1
      End If
    Next x1
  If n > 500 Then sb.Append(x & " " & x1 & " " & x3 & " " & n & vbCrLf)
  Next x
```

Comment: Could you show the equivalent VB.net version?

Comment: Loops in python are slow.  If there is a way to convert that inner loop into a list comprehension (much faster) you will see some speedup.  Or you could look at `numpy`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: not that slow, though. I'd be surprised if the VB is the exact same algorithm.

Comment: @Wooble  Let me rephrase.  Compared to equivalent list comprehensions, loops in python are slow.

Comment: Note that the `range` function actually creates a list of that range each time, so theres that. You could try swapping it out for `xrange`, which gives a generator.

Comment: @Quirliom I believe that has been fixed in python 3.

Comment: @Quirliom: `xrange` doesn't exist anymore, and `range` is an iterator. It's fixed.

Comment: @Quirliom http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux Huh, thanks for that. Interesting.

Comment: [Here](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/) is a bunch useful tools for analysing python scripts.

Comment: To add the reference, is this [CodeForces 430630 Problem B "Coin Game"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357846/numbers-of-combinations-modulo-m-efficiently#:~:text=https%3A//codeforces.com/gym/430360/problem/B)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not written particularly inefficient code, no.  You’re simply seeing a normal performance difference between a purely interpreted language (and not a particularly fast one at that) and a compiled language.  As evidence, consider the profile generated by running your code under `cProfile` for fifteen seconds:

```
% python3 -m cProfile stackoverflow.py & pid=$\!; sleep 15; kill -INT $!
55440 608
60060 608
65520 608
69300 563
73920 527
78540 608
         32855602 function calls in 14.969 seconds
   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   10.557   10.557   14.969   14.969 so.py:1(<module>)
 16427796    0.646    0.000    0.646    0.000 {built-in method abs}
        1    0.000    0.000   14.969   14.969 {built-in method exec}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method print}
 16427797    3.766    0.000    3.766    0.000 {built-in method round}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Your largest cost center appears to be the `round` function, but even that only consumes about a third of the runtime.  This suggests that the issue is not any particular part of your own code, but rather a combination of an inefficient algorithm and a slow interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not with the python math --- python math operations are as fast as in any other language. Problem is with speed of python bytecode execution, which is slow.

You can sped it up using following techniques:

- Use numpy arrays and do proper vectorisation (or array [programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)). Mind that yoy not only you need use numpy, but also you need to remove python loops using vectorisation. I have been using it, and in most of cases you can speed up calculation by 20-100 times wihout much effort.
- Use cython or weave to write code that will be directly translated to C. See [this](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html) article.

If you want to learn python I'd say that numpy is the way to go, as with cython and weave you'd learn how to write C code more.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `cython` to `C`-ify your python code. (sorry for weird `__future__`, `xrange` and percentage signs) I'm using `Python 2.7` and `ipython notebook`.

```
from __future__ import division

%%timeit
inc = 2*3*5*7
for x in xrange(inc,200000,inc):
    n = 0
    y = x * x + x
    for x1 in xrange(x+1, y):
        x2 = x1 / (x1 - x) * x
        x3 = round(x2)
        if abs(x2 - x3) < 0.0000001:
            if x3 < x1: break
            n += 1
    if n > 500: a,b = x,n

1 loops, best of 3: 1min 5s per loop


%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython -f
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
from __future__ import division
from libc.math cimport fabs
from libc.math cimport round as cround
import time
cdef int inc = 2*3*5*7
cdef int x
cdef int n
cdef int y
cdef int x1
cdef double x2
cdef double x3
cdef int a, b
t0 = time.time()
for x in range(inc,200000,inc):
    n = 0
    y = x * x + x

    for x1 in range(x+1, y):
        x2 = x1 / (x1 - x) * x
        x3 = cround(x2)
        if fabs(x2 - x3) < 0.0000001:
            if x3 < x1: break
            n += 1
    if n > 500: a,b = x,n
t1 = time.time()
print "time elapsed:", t1 - t0, "sec"

time elapsed: 0.900931119919 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is running this in pypy instead of python. Because pypy has a JIT compiler it will compile these loops down.

On my machine pypy finished in 36 seconds and python has still not returned an answer.

EDIT: I am not sure what the algorithm is trying to do, but if you are trying to see if x2 is an integer then using .is_integer halves the time that python3 takes and gets pypy down to 1 second. It appears that on some cases it returns the wrong answer, but for completeness I will include the code.

```
inc = 2*3*5*7
for x in range(inc,200000,inc):
    n = 0
    y = x * x + x

    for x1 in range(x+1, y):
        x2 = float(x1) / (x1 - x) * x
        if x2.is_integer():
            if x2 < x1: break
            n += 1
    if n > 500: print(x, n)
```

Comment: 2 minutes down to 36 seconds, on unknown hardware, is hardly a fix for 2 minutes vs <1 second

Comment: The difference between compiled language and interperted can really hurt when doing a huge amount of calculations. It doesn't really look like the poster has made some huge mistake, I was just pointing out that because it is pure python they can always try to bridge the gap with pypy.

Comment: I just tried pypy and it dropped from 123 to 98 seconds. VB is .9 seconds.

Comment: When I run this code, it takes 69 seconds on pypy 3-2.1 beta1. Is there some configuration that could cause this difference? (using is_integer breaks the algorithm, but is helpful in finding out the problem.)

Comment: Not sure you can certianly play around with passing different parameters into the jit, but I think you are basically seeing the difference between a compiled and interperted language. Doing large amounts of simple mathematical computation in python is pretty much always going to be slower than doing it in a compiled language.

Comment: Any idea why I would get 69 seconds and you get one second with the same code on pypy?

Comment: The one second is if you can use .is_integer() instead of doing a round and seeing if the abs difference is below a threshold. I thought thats what you were trying to accomplish the the computation.